# NSWindow content border not drawing correctly in El Capitan

Tags: macos, nswindow, appkit

The main window of my OSX application has a "large" bottom content border (with a height of 32).

When running under El Capitan, the background of the content border appears to be drawn at the top of the content view, however, the controls placed on the content border do display correctly. If I minimize and restore the window, everything draws correctly.

This is not an issue in Yosemite.

I have tried to call the update method on the main window subsequent to drawing, but it does not clear up the issue.

Anyone have any ideas what may be going on and/or what I can do to make the window display correctly?

Comment: I have noticed problems with content borders in El Capitan as well, but never found a solution. In the Sierra Public Beta 3, the problems seem to be fixed (so far as I can tell, anyways).